# Index will be removed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, materialized-view

I'm trying to simply change the length of a column within a table through SQL Server Management Studio, but receive a 'Validation Warning':

```
'MyTable' table
-Warning: The following schema-bound objects will be modified: 
 -View 'dbo.MyViewName': indexes and schema binding will be removed.
```

I remember from experience that if I actually go through with this, the binding will not be readded. In the past I've had to manually write a script to re-add the view. This doesn't seem right - why would it just remove it without re-adding it at the end of the operation?

It makes me think I don't have something set up correctly, or am going about this the wrong way - am I? Or is it 'correct' procedure to have to manually re-add things in this way after table changes are made?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a view with `WITH SCHEMABINDING` locks the underlying tables and prevents any changes that may change the table schema.

To change the base table you need to remove the `SCHEMABINDING` option from the objects or drop and recreate these objects once the table has been altered.

To find out if the view is schema bound use below tsql:

```
select objectproperty(object_id('view_name'), 'IsSchemaBound') as SchemaBound
```

To remove the `with schemabinding` option, just alter the view defination :

```
alter view schemaname.tablename
-- with schemabinding (remove it )
as
select some_column_name
from schema_name.table_name
```

Then make changes to the table and then alter the view again now `with schemabinding`

```
alter view schemaname.tablename
with schemabinding --(adding back )
as
select some_column_name
from schema_name.table_name
```

from [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) :

> **SCHEMABINDING :**
>
> Binds the view to the schema of the underlying table or tables. When SCHEMABINDING is specified, the base table or tables cannot be modified in a way that would affect the view definition. **The view definition itself must first be modified or dropped to remove dependencies on the table that is to be modified.** When you use SCHEMABINDING, the select_statement must include the two-part names (schema.object) of tables, views, or user-defined functions that are referenced. All referenced objects must be in the same database.
>
> **Views or tables that participate in a view created with the SCHEMABINDING clause cannot be dropped unless that view is dropped or changed so that it no longer has schema binding.** Otherwise, the Database Engine raises an error. Also, executing ALTER TABLE statements on tables that participate in views that have schema binding fail when these statements affect the view definition.

Comment: That however still permanently removes the indexes on the view. You also need to script those out and recreate them.

Comment: @SebastianMeine Good point and I forgot to add it .. You cannot have an index on a view without schemabinding, so yes the indexes are removed and when you add schemabinding back and you have to re-create the indexes. So better to scrip them first.